# The different types of pain and injuries

Tags: word-choice, words

I'm lacking a range of vocabulary that allows me to express different kinds of pain. And since I'm on this theme I might as well included injuries in this question. It seems that everything can be contained in `痛み` and `きず` but I would like to be more specific.

I shall list down the different types of injury and its corresponding pain (Not the instantaneous pain felt at the moment of injury, but the pain that persists afterwards) that I think deserve a different description because they just feel too different from each other:

1. Bruise; aching, tender(pain upon pressure)
2. Cut/Gash; sharp pain, prickly sensation
3. Abrasion; tingling/prickly sensation
4. Muscle strain; dull and sore aching (Like after rigorous exercise the muscle feels sore)
5. (For various injuries); Throbbing pain

What are their Japanese counterparts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Bruise; aching, tender(pain upon pressure)　→　あざ、打撲傷【だぼくしょう】、血豆【ちまめ】(?)
>       Cut/Gash; sharp pain, prickly sensation　→　切【き】り傷【きず】(cut, gash), {ひりひり・ぴりぴり}{する・痛む} (to sting, prickle, burn -- either a wound, or can be used to describe the feeling of eating hot/spicy foods)
>       Abrasion; tingling/prickly sensation　→　擦【す】り傷【きず】
>       Muscle strain; dull and sore aching (Like after rigorous exercise the muscle feels sore)　→　筋肉痛【きんにくつう】
>       (For various injuries); Throbbing pain　→　ずきずき{する・痛む}

Answer (score 4):

痛み refers to the sensation of pain, while きず the trace or mark left behind by the pain inflicted.

The visible cut/gash is きず. Abrasion is 擦り傷{すりきず}. But they don't refer to the pain.

For most sores or muscle aches, there are various words ending with 痛{つう}, e.g. the generic muscle sore is 筋肉痛{きんにくつう}.

When used metaphorically, 痛み still refers to the pain felt, and 傷{きず} the metaphorical 'cut'.

> 彼との{ }死別{しべつ}でできた心の傷がまだ{ }治{なお}っていない
>
> The wound in the heart from the time when seperated from him by his death has not yet healed.

For the throbbing sensation, there are many words for it: 苦痛{くつう}, 激痛{げきつう}, 疼痛{とうつう}. I think 疼痛 fits the description, but I hardly see it in use; instead, the pain is described in some other way.